# Vancouver reference problem

Tags: bibliographies

```
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
This is a citation in text\cite{Smith:2012qr}.
\bibliography{sample}
```

Produces this :

[image]

```
instead of this [1]
```

sample.bib looks like this

```
@BOOK{Smith:2012qr,
   title = {Chemistry},
   publisher = {Publisher},
   author = {Smith, J.~M. and Jones, A.~B.},
   year = {2012},
   edition = {7th},
}
```

I am using \documentclass{article}

Comment: That is not the normal output. It would be helpful if you provided an actual, but minimal(!), `.tex` file that will reproduce the output you claim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If completed to a document

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
This is a citation in text\cite{Smith:2012qr}.
\bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

then your code produces a numeric style:

[image]

So if you have an author-date style as shown in your image you presumably have some code not shown that is redefining things.

Comment: I will edit question with more information : 
I remade the .bib file and I now have the numeric style : but I want to know why it does not work with the previous .bib file so I will post more information now

Comment: @Amir that's why questions should always have _complete_ documents that reproduce the problem, it's impossible to get help on the parts that are not shown:-)

Comment: Annoyingly this problem was not reproducible, I guess it was just a problem with loading which sorted itself out when the program was reloaded. Thank you for the answer, I will mark this as the answer.